# Python 3 delete/reset variable created by decorator

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.5 and i try to delete/reset a variable created by a decorator. When i try to reset/delete `calls` i got errors. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Maybe im calling not the correct instance of the function variable? To be honest i don't understand where the variable calls is located because of the output of the pdb.

```
import inspect

def logWrapper(func):
  def wrapper_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
    wrapper_func.calls += 1
    print('Func: {}; Calls: {}' .format(func.__name__, wrapper_func.calls) )
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  wrapper_func.calls=0

  return wrapper_func


class A:

  def __init__(self):
    print('created')

  @logWrapper
  def myfunction1(self, var1):
    print('var1: {}' .format(var1))

  @logWrapper
  def myfunction2(self, var2):
    print('var2: {}' .format(var2))  

if __name__ == "__main__":   
  Pal1=A()
  Pal1.myfunction1('1')
  Pal1.myfunction1('2')
  Pal1.myfunction1('3')
  Pal1.myfunction2('A')

  function_list=inspect.getmembers(Pal1, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
  for func in function_list:
    method_to_call = getattr(Pal1, func[0])
    try:
      #try to call attribute calls if exist otherwise next function
      print( 'Result-> Function: {}; Calls: {}' .format(func[0], method_to_call.calls))
    except AttributeError:
      continue

    #Here: Only when no Exception occured
    method_to_call.calls = 0
    #del method_to_call.calls

  Pal1.myfunction1('X')
  Pal1.myfunction1('Y')
```

Output:

```
created
Func: myfunction1; Calls: 1
var1: 1
Func: myfunction1; Calls: 2
var1: 2
Func: myfunction1; Calls: 3
var1: 3
Func: myfunction2; Calls: 1
var2: A
Result-> Function: myfunction1; Calls: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tt1.py", line 41, in <module>
    method_to_call.calls = 0
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'calls'
```

PDB shows me:

```
(Pdb) method_to_call
<bound method A.__init__ of <__main__.A object at 0x022EF6B0>>
(Pdb) method_to_call
<bound method logWrapper.<locals>.wrapper_func of <__main__.A object at 0x022EF6B0>>
```

Comment: i think you didn't see the continue in the except-Block.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but the way it's written is very very confusing. Please try to cut down the code (and especially the `print` statements) to the minimum.

Comment: It might be that the get/print is getting the attribute from the class level, but the setter is attempting to set the attrib on the instance level method where it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @Dalton. `A.myfunction.calls=0` did it

Comment: The bound method object isn't what is being modified by the decorator, rather, it is the function object on the class. A bound method object is created every time you access the method

Comment: You can shorten this example to `Pal1 = A()`, `print(Pal1.myfunction1.calls)`, `Pal1.myfunction1.calls = 0`. – The rest of the code in your main block is irrelevant.

Comment: @poke: That is not correct. You can't do this.

Comment: `A.myfunction.calls=0`only works when i explizit using the functionname but i want to do this with a loop over all functions. So i can use something like `A.method_to_call.calls=0`.

Comment: @Chris I can’t do what?! You can replace your whole code starting at `if __name__ == "__main__":` with those three lines from my comment and you will get the same error caused by the same reason, just without the irrelevant stuff that will just distract from the actual problem.